# Issue while parsing timestamp into date and time using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios8, nsdate, nstimeinterval, nsinteger

I am getting `timestamp` for server in `stringFormat` which is in `miliseconds`.

I have to convert it in date and time and display to the user.

I have done it using following code:

```
    + (NSString *)getDateAndMonthFromTimeStamp:(NSString*)timestampString
{
NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [timestampString integerValue]/1000;

NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeStamp];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM"];

 NSString *dateNmonth =  [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]uppercaseString];

return dateNmonth;
}
```

When I run it in iPhone6 it works fine. But when I run it in iPhone 5 and iPhone5s it shows me unwanted date.

I debug the code and found this:

```
  timestampString = @"1459498716000"

  NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [timestampString integerValue]/1000; 
 //after this timeStamp becomes:
  timeStamp = 2147483;
```

and then my date becomes `1970-01-25 20:31:23 +0000`

I am in doubt that `NSTimeinterval` is overflowed with data. is this right?

How can I fix this.

Comment: store timestamp value in double datatype

Comment: @DarjiJigar using double doesn't solved my problem.

Comment: if you get timestamp data in json string than why u convert in nstimeinterval

Comment: apply this code NSString* takeOffTime = @"1396614600000";
double miliSec = takeOffTime.doubleValue;
NSDate* takeOffDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:miliSec/1000];

Comment: sorry it was using double in wrong way..now double working fine

Comment: ok i uploadmy answer pls upvote bro

Comment: bro i will upload my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
NSString* takeOffTime = @"1396614600000"; 
double miliSec = takeOffTime.doubleValue; 
NSDate* takeOffDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:miliSec/1000];
```